# Iconutil giving error

Tags: xcode4

I have been getting this error for 2 days in response to iconutil -c icns iconset.iconset:
ImageIO:   _CGImagePluginWriteICNS unsupported image size (128 x 128) - scaling factor: 2
ImageIO:   _CGImagePluginWriteICNS unsupported image size (16 x 16) - scaling factor: 2
The iconset.iconset folder has 10 .png files icon_512x512@2x.png, icon_512x512.png...and the versions for 256, 128, 32, 16.
The resulting iconset.icns file has only 8 images.
I'm running xcode 4.5 on Lion.
I have searched and searched for an answer. If I just remove the offending 128x128@2x and the 16x16@2x, the message is these files are missing.
Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Anything I can do to improve the chances of getting an answer to this problem with iconutil?

Comment: Yes... format the question correctly, so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the answer to my question:
The @2x files should have an image size 2x, e.g. icon_128x128.png has image size 128x128 px, but icon_128x128@2x.png actually must have an image size of 256x256 px.
When I asked the question, I did not realize this and my image sizes were the same for each pair.
Hope this helps someone